# Equivalent of scss @import for styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making an embeddable widget with react and styled-components, and want to do a big CSS reset in my main app container. I'm going to use the styles from [cleanslate](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) to do that, however I don't want to just drop it into my main styled component because it's 400 lines long. Ideally, those styles would live in a separate js file, and then in `StyledApp` I'd do something similar to scss' `@import cleanslate`.

The suggestions I've found include make a separate call to the CDN version of the css file, but I don't want to do that for two reasons: 1. don't want the extra performance hit, 2. I want to make edits.

Is there a way I can import all of those styles into my main `StyledApp` and have them applied to that app component?

Comment: Do have an option to edit the theme?

Comment: I can edit my own theme in styled-components, yes. I need to use a clean css base, however, to ensure I don't get affected by styles on the parent site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare css styles with the `css` helper from `styled-components` and then invoke it where you need it:

```
export const cleanSlateRules = css`
// styles
`;

export const StyledWhatever = styled.div`
  ${cleanSlateRules}
`;
```

EDIT: Turns out this currently doesn't work in prod. I think because of the same issue as the [@import](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#note-regarding-css-import-and-createglobalstyle) problem.

EDIT 2: I got this to work in production using the babel plugin for styled components. The custom css was successfully applied after that. See my answer here: [styled-components only rendering certain styles after successful build with parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188847/styled-components-only-rendering-certain-styles-after-successful-build-with-parc)